# How to get Trending Tweets using twitterizer?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twitter

I am looking to display the current trending tweets using Twitterizer. I am using the following code to try to generate the  current trends .

```
 public TwitterResponse<TwitterTrendCollection> 
                GetTrendingTweets(string 
                accesstoken, string accesstokensecreat, double lati, double longi)
        {
            OAuthTokens tokens = SetTokens(accesstoken, accesstokensecreat);
            LocalTrendsOptions options = new LocalTrendsOptions();
            options.UseSSL = true;
            options.APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
            PlaceInfo p = GetWoeid(lati, longi);
            AvailableTrendsOptions option = new AvailableTrendsOptions() { Lat = 
            lati, Long = longi };
            TwitterResponse<TwitterTrendCollection> trends = 
            TwitterTrend.Trends(tokens, (int)p.Woeid, options);
            return trends;
        }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What i am getting is trends and hashtags,perhaps i am looking for trending tweets, is there any  way to do it ? please help